# Pandas slow multiIndex assignment of a tuple

Tags: python, pandas, performance, multi-index

I create an empty DataFrame and I want to add rows to it.

```
ret = pd.DataFrame(columns=['TIME','TYPE'] + list(range(len(pointsA)) + list(range(len(pointsB))))
ret = ret.set_index(['TIME', 'TYPE'])
```

At this point, I have an empty DataFrame with the following structure:

```
              1   2   3   4   5   1   2   3   4   5
(TIME, TYPE)
```

Now I want to manually add 2 rows to this DataFrame:

```
ret.loc[(current_time, 'A'),:] = tuple(pointsA.index) + tuple(pointsA.values)
ret.loc[(current_time, 'B'),:] = tuple(pointsB.index) + tuple(pointsB.values)
```

But this is very slow to execute. Is there a better way to do it?